# How can reuse onClickListener in Android

Tags: java, android, performance, android-button

I'm having one activity containing many buttons and each button performs different task. Since, I'm using push notifications to perform separate task every time for different notification, What is the best way to simulate the onClick Event.

One way I thought is using function. Writing separate function and calling it in onClickListener. Is there any other way to achieve the objective?

```
  btnengg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (netconnect(null)==1)
            {
                w.loadUrl("myurl1");
                wtshare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            else
            {
            mInterstitialAd.show();

            pbb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fadView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            w.loadUrl("myurl2");
                requestNewInterstitial();

            }}
    });
```

Comment: you want a single listener for all your buttons?

Comment: No. But what I'm going to do it whenever I send the push notification, it should manipulate the touch activity to the specific button.

Comment: You need to write separate methods for each of your different tasks, then call the method in click listeners and in the notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Assign OnClickListener to a field and set it as click listener and based on button Id perform relative action

```
OnClickListener buttonClickListener = button -> {
    switch (button.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            break;
    }
};

button.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
```

In case you are asking how to initiate click action programmatically, you can
    button.performClick();